# bring window to top level

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to present several questions, one after another. The first question is shown as I like, with the cursor set in the entry field. Then I destroy the window and call the function again to create a new window. This time the window is not shown in the front and therefore I first have to click on the screen in order to have the cursor set to the entry field. Also the escape key does not work until I click on the screen to bring the window to the top. I'd be very happy for your help! 
Thank you in advance!
Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def text_input_restricted(fn,question, nr_letters, limit, len_min, len_max,keys, justify):

    class MyApp():

         def validate(root, S):
                return all(c in keys for c in S) 

         def __init__(self, q= None):

            #save response after "next"-button has been clicked    
            def okClicked():
                 lines = e.get()
                 if len_min < len(lines) < len_max:
                     lines = unicode(lines).encode('utf-8')
                     datFile = open(fn, "a")                      
                     datFile.write(" '%s'"%(lines))
                     datFile.close() 
                     self.root.destroy()

            self.root = Tk()
            vcmd = (self.root.register(self.validate), '%S')

            #quit if escape-key has been pressed
            self.root.bind('<Escape>', lambda q: quit())                 

            #colors
            color = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (200, 200, 200) 
            self.root.configure(bg=color)

            #set window size to screen size
            RWidth=MAXX
            RHeight=MAXY
            self.root.geometry(("%dx%d")%(RWidth,RHeight)) 

            #remove buttons (cross, minimize, maximize)
            self.root.overrideredirect(1) 

            #remove title
            self.root.title("")  

            #item
            labelWidget = Label(self.root,text=question, font=("Arial", int(0.02*MAXX)), bd=5, bg=color, justify="center")
            labelWidget.place(x=0, y=RHeight/40,width=RWidth)   

            #"next"-button    
            ok_width = RWidth/15
            ok_height = RWidth/15 
            okWidget = Button(self.root, text= "next", command = okClicked, font=("Arial",int(0.015*MAXX)), bd=5, justify="center")    
            okWidget.place(x=RWidth/2-ok_width/2,y=13*RHeight/40, width=ok_width,height=ok_height) 

            def callback(sv): 
                c = sv.get()[0:limit]
                sv.set(c)    

            sv = StringVar()
            width=nr_letters * int(0.02*MAXX)*1.3
            sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: callback(sv))

            e = Entry(self.root, textvariable=sv,font=("Arial", int(0.02*MAXX)),justify=justify,validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)           
            e.place(x=RWidth/2-width/2, y=9*RHeight/40, width=width)

            #show cursor
            e.focus_set() 

            self.root.mainloop() 

    MyApp()


MAXX=1366
MAXY=768
fn = "D:/test.dat"    
text_input_restricted(fn = fn, question=u"f for female, m for male", nr_letters=1, limit =1, len_min =0, len_max=2, keys = 'fm', justify="center")

text_input_restricted(fn = fn, question="How old are you?", nr_letters=2,limit=2, len_min = 1, len_max = 3, keys = '1234567890',justify="center")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tk you use the [raise](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/raise.htm) command to bring a window to the front of the Z-order. However, raise is a keyword in Python so this has been renamed to `lift`. Provided your application is still the foreground application you can call the *lift()* method on a toplevel widget. If the application is not the foreground application then this will raise the window but only above other windows from the same application. On Windows this causes the taskbar icon for your application to start flashing.

You might do better to destroy the contents of the toplevel and replace them. Or even better - create a number of frames holding each 'page' of your application and toggle the visibility of each frame by packing and pack_forgetting (or grid and grid forget). This will avoid loosing the focus completely - you can just set the focus onto the first widget of each frame as you make it visible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! Destroying everything would be the solution I'd prefer as it seems the easiest one (I'm a beginner in programming). However, so far I did not manage to get everything destroyed. I used the command self.root.destroy()  (see def okClicked()). Which command do I have to use to destroy everything? Thanks for you help!

Comment: To destroy all the child windows of a toplevel widget called "dlg* use something like `for w in dlg.winfo_children(): w.destroy()`. If you destroy the Tk main window you basically terminate Tk. The code example here should iterate over all the children and call their destroy methods in turn, leaving the toplevel alone so that you can re-populate it later.